# NSDateFormatter strange dateFromString behaviour

Tags: nsdate, nsdateformatter

I use an NSDateFormatter to get an NSDate from an incoming string. I have this code:

```
stringToUpdate = [stringToUpdate stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"T" withString:@" "];

NSMutableString* dateWithoutColonString = [stringToUpdate mutableCopy];

NSRegularExpression* lastColonRegex = [NSRegularExpression
                                       regularExpressionWithPattern:@"([\\+\\-][0-9][0-9]):"
                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                       error:nil];

[lastColonRegex replaceMatchesInString:dateWithoutColonString
                               options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                 range:NSMakeRange(0, [stringToUpdate length])
                          withTemplate:@"$1"];

NSDateFormatter *dateformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateformatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ssZZZ"];

NSDate *myDate = [dateformatter dateFromString: dateWithoutColonString];
```

which is behaving differently for different incoming strings. Meaning:

```
NSString *stringToUpdate = @"2013-02-05T17:20:58+01:00";
```

always fails, while

```
NSString *stringToUpdate = @"2013-02-07T12:26:41+01:00";
```

always succeeds. The length of the incoming string is identical for both, so there shouldn't be any functional characters. Any hints what's going on would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: 17:20 is on a 24 hour clock, so you need to use HH in the format specification instead of hh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DateFromString seems to be simply buggy. Use:

```
if (![[self dateformatter] getObjectValue:&myDate forString:stringToUpdate range:nil error:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Date '%@' could not be parsed: %@", stringToUpdate, error);
} else {
    //NSLog(@"%@", myDate);
}

NSString *text;

NSTimeInterval timeInSeconds = [myDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
timeInSeconds = timeInSeconds * -1;
```

to get positive number of seconds.